# Table row being deleted due to knockout code

Tags: knockout.js

I'm attempting to make some enhancements to an ASP.NET MVC 4 app that makes heavy use of knockout.js and the MVVM pattern in the browser. I'm picking up knockout and I really like it but I've managed to cause an unexpected bug.

I have a table and am using the foreach look in the data-bind attribute that loops through a knockout viewmodel and creates the rows.

In the viewmodel I've added a few more attributes to support a new footer row that totals up the numeric columns in the table.

Unfortunately, the attributes I added in the viewmodel are causing a row to get removed when I post back to the controller. I suspect I am using the wrong knockout construct to add these totals...

...this is within the view model...

```
self.BudgetTotal = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0;
    //The problem is this loop! It's messing with the Phases observable array and it's all magic behind the scenes and I can't see what's going wrong
    for (i = 0; i < self.Phases().length; i++)
        total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(self.Phases()[i].Total());
    return format_number(total, 2);
});
```

This is the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-compact">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Phase</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Phase Manager</th>
                        <th>Labor</th>
                        <th>Expense</th>
                        <th>Subs</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="template: {foreach: Phases.sort(function (l, r) { return l.Code() > r.Code() ? 1 : -1 }) }">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected, click:SelectionChanged"/></td>
                        <td class="phasecode" data-bind="text: Code"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Name, visible: IsAdditional" class="input-small phaseName" maxlength = "35"/><span data-bind="text: Name, visible: !IsAdditional()"></span></td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" id="CompanyCode" data-bind="value: Company().Code" /><input type="text" class="PhaseManagerTypeahead phaseManager" data-bind="value: PhaseManager().CodeName, enable: IsSelected" autocomplete="off"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <nobr><input class="span1" id="inputIcon" type="text" data-bind="value: Labor, enable: IsSelected" style="text-align:right" onblur="checkDecimal(this)" maxlength = "20"/></nobr>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <nobr><input class="span1" id="inputIcon" type="text" data-bind="value: Expenses, enable: IsSelected" style="text-align:right" onblur="checkDecimal(this)" maxlength = "20"/></nobr>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <nobr><input class="span1" id="inputIcon" type="text" data-bind="value: Subcontractor, enable: IsSelected" style="text-align:right" onblur="checkDecimal(this)" maxlength = "20"/></nobr>
                        </td>
                        <td data-bind="text: Total" style="min-width:80px; text-align:right"></td>
                    </tr>                                            
                </tbody>
                <tfoot class="hideFromPrinter">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind='click: viewModel.addAdditionalPhase'>Add Additional Phase...</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

I removed the footer row that displays the totals but found that it's unrelated to the bug. If I comment out the knockout code above, the bug disappears. When I uncomment it, the bug returns.

The solution was to iterate over the observable array using the utility function arrayForEach.

```
self.BudgetTotal = ko.computed(function () {
var total = 0;
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Phases, function (item) {
    var value = parseFloat(item.Total());
    if(!isNaN(value))
        total += value;
    }
);
return total.toFixed(2);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using knockouts arrayForEach works around the issue:

```
self.BudgetTotal = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Phases, function (item) {
        var value = parseFloat(item.Total());
        if(!isNaN(value))
            total += value;
    );
    return total.toFixed(2);
});
```

A google search led me to this block which advises using the arrayForEach.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Answer (score 1):

Your bindings are the problem. You saying that you are binding to template, but there is no template name specified. Just bind using foreach and it will work:

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Phases">
   <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
```

Or specify template name:

```
  <tbody data-bind="template: { foreach: Phases, name: 'row-template'}">
  </tbody>

  <script type="text\html" id="row-template">
    <tr>...</tr>
  </script>
```

Comment: The table itself displays fine and all of the data binding works. The applyBindings call is done elsewhere.

Comment: So then I'm not sure what your issue is. It is displaying data, but missing one row?

Comment: When the user clicks any button that does an HTTP Post back to the server, a row is being removed from this table. I've isolated the issue to the viewmodel code I added but, I cannot see any way that that code would impact the number of rows in the table.

Comment: What do you mean by HTTP Post back? Are you using ASP.NET forms?

Comment: MVC. The bug occurs when I post the form back to the controller. Get's don't cause the issue.